# Passing a variable to the new.html.rb page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I have two MVCs Meeting and Agenda. A meeting can have many agenda items.

I am trying to set these two pages up so that I can click a 'Create New Agenda Item' on the show.html.rb meeting page. The idea being that this would redirect the user to the new.html.rb agenda page passing the meeting id, and pre-populating the new.html.rb agenda form with the meeting ID.

Currently I have the following which passes the meeting ID in the URL but I have no idea how to pass it to the form.

Meeting: show.html.rb:

```
<%= link_to "Add Agenda Item", :action => 'new_agenda', :id => @meeting.id %>
```

Go gentle, I'm very new. But many thanks in advance.

Christian Macedo.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` action within your Agenda controller should have access to the meeting ID query parameter. Something like:

```
def new
  @agenda = Agenda.new
  @agenda.meetings.build(Meeting.find(params[:id]))
end
```

Comment: Ok, I tried adding this, however I now get an error when clicking the link for a new agenda item.

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.build

Even if this weren't the case. I dont understand how the second line of code is obtaining the id of the meeting that I've passed in the URL. 

I think I am very much missing something here. Or just plain old practice.

Comment: Try changing it to `@agenda.meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])`. The meeting ID is passed in the `params` hash. See here for details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#querystring-parameters

Comment: That won't work, because params[:id] would give you the Agenda's id if you were in the new Agenda view. If Agenda is a nested resource of Meeting, you can do params[:meeting_id] though. Also, @agenda.meetings doesn't make sense because Meetings have many Agendas, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm going to take that back. If you passed it into the new Agenda view as :id, you should be able to access it as params[:id].